# Emulate ".contains()" in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I have a dataset in Reporting Services that looks something like this:

```
 ID  |  Type  | Name   
-----+--------+--------  
  1  |   A    | Mary  
  2  |   A    | Joe  
  3  |   D    | Steve  
 12  |   F    | Irving
```

I want to show a textbox IF AND ONLY IF there exists a row where type = A. Basically, I want to do "Fields!Type.Contains("A")" and bind the visibility to the result. Is this a backwards approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an invisible column with an expression that returns 1 if the value of the Type column is A. Create a sum of that column and use that in the expression behind the visibility property of your TextBox.

Comment: I think you might even be able to do the same thing using First or Max without the extra column